# Getting Synthetic Base Event in console instead of that particular item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

Below is the code. Whenever I am clicking on add to cart, for every item. I can see an alert.
And Instead of item if I console.log something static it is also working but with item. I am getting a Synthetic Base Event in console

```
function Product() {
    useEffect (() => {
        fetchItems();
    },[]);

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchItems = async() => {
        const data = await fetch('/product',{
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            credentials: "include"
        });
        const items = await data.json();
        setItems(items);
    };

    const clickMe = (item) => {
        alert("Working");
        console.log(item);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Product Page</h1>

            {
                items.map(item => (
                    <p>{item.productname} {item.productprice}  {item.type} <a onClick={clickMe.bind(item)}>add to cart</a> </p>
                ))
            }

        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `.bind` doesn't do what you think it does.

[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

With `onClick={clickMe.bind(item)}` you are only binding `item` to the `this` of the function and the `onClick` event is still passed as the first argument to the callback.

If you are wanting to pass the currently mapped `item` then this needs to be passed as an additional argument.

```
onClick={clickMe.bind(null, item)}
```

You could also just use an anonymous callback function.

```
onClick={() => clickMe(item)}
```

Or declare `clickMe` to be a curried function and return the click handler with the `item` closed over in callback scope.

```
const clickMe = (item) => () => {
    alert("Working");
    console.log(item);
};

...

onClick={clickMe(item)}
```

Comment: @DrewResse I did make the changes but for some reason , without clicking on anything . I am automatically getting the alert. items.map(item => (
                    <p>{item.productname} {item.productprice}  {item.type} <button onClick={clickMe(item)}>
                    Add to cart
                  </button></p>
                ))

Comment: @RitikSingh Looks like you want with option 3, the curried function. did you catch that `clickMe` is updated to be a function that returns a function? i.e. `(arg) => () => {}`? The first function is immediately invoked, so if not returning another function the body is executed.